# how to configuring WIN 7 as Access point and using proxy

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, proxy

[info] :

- The connection : phone to computer to modem to internet.
- Modem IP : 192.168.123.1
- Computer IP : 192.168.123.1
- Computer OS Windows 7
- Phone connection : Wifi (*using Internet Connection Sharing and addressed : 192.168.0.1*)

[problem]
Computer internet connection **can** through proxy but when i using internet on the phone it directly connect to modem without go through proxy first.

How to configuring computer if want to all internet connection from both computer and phone through proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to change proxy settings in browser **on the phone**, rather than configure the computer.

Unless the computer was a Linux, then you could install **squid** and reroute packets :-)